# Let $x_n\leq y_n$ for each $n\in \Bbb N$. Show that $\liminf x_n \leq \liminf y_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

Let $x_n\leq y_n$ for each $n\in \Bbb N$. Then,

$$\liminf x_n \leq \liminf y_n$$

Here is a solution for the above problem ( source:https://math.stackexchange.com/a/934738/199156)

> Define $u_n:=\inf\{x_k|k\geq n\}$ and $v_n:=\inf\{y_k|k\geq n\}$.
>
> Then the sequence $(u_n)$ is non-decreasing and satisfies
> $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}u_n=\liminf x_n$.
>
> Likewise $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}v_n=\liminf y_n$.
>
> From $x_m\leq y_m$ for each $m$ it follows directly that $u_m\leq v_m$
> for each $m$ and consequenly $\liminf x_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}u_n\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}v_n=\liminf y_n$

However, I was wondering if it can be done using the definition of $\lim\limits_{n \to  \infty} \inf x_{n}=\underset{n \geq 1}{\sup} \underset{k \geq n}{\inf} x_{k}$ instead.

Comment: And how do you define $\liminf$ and $\limsup$?

Comment: @SmithPay The top answer on the linked comment seems to use exactly this definition, so I don't understand the issue

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you for pointing this out. It seems like that I am missing something in here and do not completely understand the point that is being made.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea in the linked proof can also be expressed as follows.

As you note, we have $\liminf x_n = \sup_{n \geq 1} \inf_{k \geq n} x_k$. We note that because $x_k \leq y_k$ for each $n$, it must hold that for any $n \in \Bbb N$, we have
$$
\inf_{k \geq n} x_k \leq \inf_{k \geq n} y_k.
$$
Now, let $X_n = \inf_{k \geq n} x_k$, and similarly $Y_n = \inf_{k \geq n} y_k$. We have established that $X_n \leq Y_n$ holds for each $n$. It follows that
$$
\sup_{n \geq 1} X_n \leq \sup_{n \geq 1} Y_n.
$$
That is, we have $\liminf x_n \leq \liminf y_n$, which is what we wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $x=\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n>\liminf_{n\to\infty}y_n=y$. Now since $y$ is the limit of a subsequence of $\{y_n\}_n$, it means that after a threshold all the points of that subsequence of $\{y_n\}_n$ are less than $x$. Consider the subsequence in $\{x_n\}_n$ corresponding to these indices, and you'll get a subsequence of $\{x_n\}_n$ all of whose terms are less than $x$ after a threshold. This is a contradiction.